# php report for last x months grouped by months and days

Tags: php, date, loops

I am trying to create a php report in which data gets grouped by months and then days (and then time slots for each day--but that can wait a while). The format is something like:

2013->April->Monday->Data

2013->April->Tuesday->Data

...

2012->December->Monday->Data

...

I have the following code:

```
 $lastmonth = strtotime ( '-'.$monthrange.' month' , strtotime ("now")) ;
 $arr_months = array();
 $timestampformonths = strtotime("now");
 $arr_daysofweek = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i < $monthrange; $i++) {
   $arr_months[] = strftime('%B', $timestampformonths);
   $timestampformonths = strtotime('-1 month', $timestampformonths);
 }
//tempdump($arr_months);tempstop();//April,March,February...

//build array of days of week backward, starting today
$timestampfordays = strtotime("now");
$arr_daysofweek = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
 $arr_daysofweek[] = strftime('%A', $timestampfordays);
 $timestampfordays = strtotime('-1 day', $timestampfordays);
}

foreach ($arr_daysofweek as $dayoftheweek) {
 foreach ($arr_months as $currmonth) {
    $currmonth_datetime = strtotime($currmonth);
    $prevmonth_datetime = strtotime('-1 month', $currmonth_datetime);
     for($i = strtotime($dayoftheweek, $currmonth_datetime); ( ($i >= $lastmonth) && ($i <= strtotime("now")) && ($currmonth_datetime > $prevmonth_datetime) ); $i = strtotime('-1 week', $i)) {
        echo date('l Y-m-d', $i) . "<br />";//Monday 2012-04-02 00:00:00
    }
}
```

}

There is a problem with this code: 
There are repeats. For example, the output currently starts as 'Wednesday 2013-04-03' and then displays through 'Wednesday 2012-04-04' fine but then again displays 'Wednesday 2013-03-06'; I think it is the loop for the month inside the loop for the days.

Please feel free to completely redo this code! I won't even mind removing the foreach loop for the $arr_daysof week and instead hardcode a few loops for each day--though that would not be elegant.

Thanks!

*** Code update: I think I have fixed the problem of repeats; will post more later if needed ***

Comment: Note, for problem #2, I can probably build the arr_daysofweek by starting from 'now' to get the current day

Comment: Depending on the size and quantity of those reports, it might be faster to copy these in a database then retrieve them on the fly when one is requested. Databases are optimized for such operations.

Comment: Thanks, Nilocal. But database is not an option in this case. Eventually the data will come through API calls to a server but right now I just need to figure out the php's dates/loops..

Comment: *** I have reconstructed the arr_daysofweek and now the results look better--may be even a solution!*** Will post here soon any progress or updated question***

Comment: I have updated the code; still need help.